# Is 'foreach' faster than a 'for' loop?

Tags: java

I have solved this [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/) problem [Valid Anagram](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-anagram) with the following solution, which achieved a runtime of 4 ms.

```java
class Solution {
    public boolean isAnagram(String s, String t) {
        if (s.length() != t.length()) {
            return false;
        }

        int[] countArray = new int[26];
        char[] a = s.toCharArray();
        char[] b = t.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            countArray[a[i] - 'a']++;
            countArray[b[i] - 'a']--;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            if (countArray[i] != 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

However, I noticed that someone used this solution with a *foreach* loop that took only 2 ms.

```java
class Solution {
    public boolean isAnagram(String s, String t) {
        if (s.length() != t.length()) {
            return false;
        }

        int[] countArray = new int[26];
        for (char ch : s.toCharArray()) {
            countArray[ch - 'a']++;
        }

        for (char ch : t.toCharArray()) {
            countArray[ch - 'a']--;
        }

        for (int count : countArray) {
            if (count != 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Why is *foreach* faster in this case, despite having to iterate through the array two times?

Comment: They compile to very similar bytecode. The major difference is the two loops which might be better to optimize- each loop works on it's own array, a contiguous block of memory. This could easily be vectorized by a smart JVM, or at least goes easier on the CPU cache.

Comment: I'm surprised that the difference is quite so large but I would expect there is a cost to updating the loop variable and explicit indexing in the first code which can be largely eliminated in the second and will also vectorise better.

Comment: It should be bench marked. Is leet code explaining how they're calcuating the result? If they just run the result, this seems within a margin of error. I wouldn't be surprised if both loops end up making similar optimizations.

Comment: Note that I tried to run both codes multiple times, and the runtime is the same. @Clashsoft might be correct.

Comment: "_Note that I tried to run both codes multiple times, and the runtime is the same_" -- Use JMH to create benchmarks and then see what the results are.

Comment: It doesn’t matter. Unless you have nothing in your ‘for’ loop body, it running time will dominate the running time of the loop.

Comment: The point of the  `for (int count`... is readability and not having to mess with a loop index. If you really think your code is too slow, profile it to see where it's spending its time. Optimize those hot spots. The loop syntax is probably not a hot spot.

Answer (score 2):

LeetCode performance metrics are not exact.

It differs if you run your code multiple times. For example, it can depend on current available resources, context switching, etc.

Although, the loop does not use an iterator, only access elements by indexes, but I don't think that there is some difference in performance.

I think that your solution can be slower due to creating ***intermediate arrays*** (a,b).

Comment: The other code also creates intermediate arrays (with `s.toCharArray()` and `t.toCharArray()`). I wonder if the difference isn't about accessing `a` and `b` in one and the same loop, and if maybe using one loop for `a` and one loop for `b` (similar to how there are two loops in the for-each variant) might perform better than the single loop over both.

Comment: Yeah, I see.

What I think (I am not sure about it) is that you access multiple times in the first code.

You access arrays: a, b, and 2x countArray. Accessing arrays requires computing memory addresses, and items can be scattered across memory, potentially leading to cache misses, etc.

So maybe this is the reason..

Comment: But that access also happens in the for-each case, it's just hidden from you. And for a `char`-array, that is sequential memory access, nothing is scattered across memory.